# Media query doesn't update in rotating for iphone 4 and iphone 5s

Tags: css, media-queries, viewport, iphone-4

CSSs in Media query doesn't update, when I rotate iPhone 4 and iPhone 5s between portrait and landscape.

Since I use viewport measure, vw and vh, in media query css, I expect that they are re-applied in rotating between portrait and landscape - they work totally fine in all phones except iPhone 4 and iPhone 5s. When I rotate from portrait to landscape, the width in portrait remains in landscape, too.

I don't understand why only iPhone 4 and iPhone 5s have this issue. Must there be some problems in my css?

[Edit] Pieces of the codes are below:

```css
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 640px)
{
...
.products .product .info
{
    width: 80vw;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
...
}
```

The 80vw keeps the same width, when I rotate from Portrait to landscape in iPhone 4. If I refresh the page in landscape, the physical width of 80vw doesn't change. Can I get any help for it?

Comment: Provide some code please. Media query breakpoints.

Comment: Petroff, I just added some sample codes and a problem about them.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some good examples taken from [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

```css
/* iPhone 4 (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 5 (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 5 (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6 (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6 (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6+ (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6+ (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but, my problem is that the css doesn't apply when rotating in iPhone 4.